# How to implement a secret url for delivering information after payment without login?

Tags: php, url

I would like to deliver some information to customers after a paypal payment, using the paypal return url, and without having the customer log in.

So I think I need a system to create urls for each transaction, and to avoid that a url for another transaction is guessed.

I have thought of something like:

> http://www.domain.com/product/send.php?productID=12&transactionHash=[thisTransactionHash]

using a transactionHash that could be calculated based on the customer's email and the product unique id.

Does this method make sense? or what would be your recommendation delivering information without login, and avoiding customers guessing the url for other products?

---

Although they were several interesting answers about hashes, there is still one concern with the idea I mention above: Paypal needs to receive the return url, therefore the information is passed before payment and therefore the method is not securing against fraud.

The only secure way I see is the Paypal delivery system, which is why I accepted that answer.

Comment: This is Security through obscurity.

Comment: @Yousf Ok, does this mean you recommend a login/password system?

Comment: It's only _security through obscurity_ if the used transaction hash is calculated based on known data. If its generated randomly that should be a safe method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you target PayPal only, why don't you check Instant Payment Notification Guide?
https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/ipnguide.pdf

I didn't use Paypal before, but it seems this solves your problem.

Create table:
| product_id (unique ID of you product) | varchar transaction_hash |

In this sample code (PHP example):
https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216623

After validating that the payment is correct, insert product ID and verify_sign( value from paypal POST data) in the table. and Give the user a URL with with product ID and verify_sign.

Answer (score 1):

"using a transactionHash that could be calculated based on the customer's email and the product unique id."

As soon as the algorithm gets known you system will break down. My recommendation is a "secure" aka cryptographic PRNG + some lookup table.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a random id for a user at any given time you want, maybe even using some truely random generators out on the web.

BUT what you should do is make it UNIQUE for a specific amount of time, perhaps with a simple database structure, maybe storing informations into files on your server, that will be deleted by the same script as soon as they're read once, depends on your needs.

So whenever a user generates such unique ID he can access that information for either a certain period of time, or exactly once.

Using say random.org's random byte function you can generate a string like:
6f0d47cf3432d4015e0e798641191bf0e8e0b90b00df23181bcb3401a0dad43d85be711343c3baa9
Which is nearly impossible to guess even if someone else knows a productID AND the emailadress of said customer

Answer (score 1):

Using a hash to access some stored information without the need of logging in isn't a bad idea. BUT that hash should not be generated based on already known data like IDs, email-address or similar data that could be known or guessed by any user.

Instead it is necessary to randomly generate a long enough hash thats value couldn't be guessed or generated out of any known data.
The already mentioned byte function from random.org could be a good choice for that.

Answer (score 0):

include a hash param which value is calculated based on several parameters. for example, for your url o would calculate the hash like this:

```
$uniqueKeyString="some random characters";
transactionHash=md5("domain.com".$productId.time().$uniqueKeyString);
```

where `$uniqueKeyString` is a secret value (some random integer) only you know.
than, when a request will come to your servers, you can simply calculate the hash string yourself and compare it with the `transactionHash` of the request whether it is the same.

Comment: and yes, to improve security you can use better hash functions than md5 and pls use a longer unique key string.